# SqlException was unhandled by user code, incorrect syntax near '3'

Tags: sqlexception

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBjQz.jpg)

Hi guys,

I have this error whereby sqlException was unhandled by user code, incorrect syntax near 3.

below is my code.

```
private void get3GSiteID()
    {
        string name3G = "";

        DataTable dtSite = new DataTable();            

        sqlStr = " SELECT ";
        sqlStr += " SNumb ";
        sqlStr += " FROM ";
        sqlStr += " 3G.DBO.W_Site AS W_SITE";
        sqlStr += " WHERE ";
        sqlStr += " W_SITE.Address = '" + siteAddress + "'";            
        SqlDataAdapter daSite = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, tGConnection3G);
        dtSite.Clear();
        daSite.Fill(dtSite);
        if (dtSite.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            name3G = dtSite.Rows[0]["SNumb"].ToString();
            siteIDCheckBox.Add(name3G);
            bssNetworkList.Add("3G");
        }
    }
```

Please do help.
i've been stuck here for 2 days already..

Thanks

Comment: In order to figure out the problem, you'll need to help out by specifying the values being used when the exception happens (`SNumb`, `siteAddress`).  That will at least allow us to see what the SQL command causing the exception is...

Comment: ok SNumb is site003
and siteAddress is blk 123 good road

Comment: So the SQL statement causing the exception is `SELECT site003 from 3G.DBO.W_Site AS W_SITE WHERE W_SITE.Address = 'blk 123 good road'` ?  Which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: Im not sure about that. The database was created by another person.

Comment: yeap ill do just that :)

Comment: i only have access to the system on monday, so ill try it then

Comment: hi sorry ive just managed to try it, now ive got a new error saying invalid object name.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Dave, i've managed to solve the answer, its not [3G.DBO.W_Site] but rather [3G].DBO.W_Site

```
private void get3GSiteID()
{
    string name3G = "";

    DataTable dtSite = new DataTable();            

    sqlStr = " SELECT ";
    sqlStr += " SNumb ";
    sqlStr += " FROM ";
    sqlStr += " **[3G]**.DBO.W_Site AS W_SITE";
    sqlStr += " WHERE ";
    sqlStr += " W_SITE.Address = '" + siteAddress + "'";            
    SqlDataAdapter daSite = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, tGConnection3G);
    dtSite.Clear();
    daSite.Fill(dtSite);
    if (dtSite.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        name3G = dtSite.Rows[0]["SNumb"].ToString();
        siteIDCheckBox.Add(name3G);
        bssNetworkList.Add("3G");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; In SQL Server the [rules for database identifiers state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) that

> The first character must be one of the following: A letter as defined
> by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters
> includes Latin characters from a through z, from A through Z, and also
> letter characters from other languages.
>
> The underscore (_), at sign
> (@), or number sign (#).
>
> Certain symbols at the beginning of an
> identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier
> that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or
> parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object.
> An identifier that starts with a number sign denotes a temporary table
> or procedure. An identifier that starts with double number signs (##)
> denotes a global temporary object. Although the number sign or double
> number sign characters can be used to begin the names of other types
> of objects, we do not recommend this practice. Some Transact-SQL
> functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid
> confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start
> with @@.

Since you're trying to query the database, presumably it already exists, which means to get to it you'll need to delimit the name with double quotes or square brackets.

```
private void get3GSiteID()
    {
        string name3G = "";

        DataTable dtSite = new DataTable();            

        sqlStr = " SELECT ";
        sqlStr += " SNumb ";
        sqlStr += " FROM ";
        sqlStr += " [3G.DBO.W_Site] AS W_SITE";
        sqlStr += " WHERE ";
        sqlStr += " W_SITE.Address = '" + siteAddress + "'";            
        SqlDataAdapter daSite = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, tGConnection3G);
        dtSite.Clear();
        daSite.Fill(dtSite);
        if (dtSite.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            name3G = dtSite.Rows[0]["SNumb"].ToString();
            siteIDCheckBox.Add(name3G);
            bssNetworkList.Add("3G");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Thank you so much for ur answer. But I think i tried that. But it had another exception which says invalid object [3G.DBO.W_Site]. Not sure if i made any mistake anywhere. Funny thing was the same code works for all other databases which does not start with a number like the reason that u stated.

Comment: I do not have access to the system now. I guess ill try ur answer again on monday.

Comment: hi sorry ive just managed to try it, now ive got a new error saying invalid object name.

Comment: Did you find out which database system you're using?  It will help